# Getting a Error processing pipeline error in when processing Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The command I am running:
python3 -m     apache_beam.examples.wordcount     --region us-central1 --input     gs://dataflow-`samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt     --output     gs://STORAGE_BUCKET/results/output     --runner DataflowRunner     --project     traffic-prediction-317805     --temp_location     gs://STORAGE_BUCKET/temp/`

Getting the following error when running a Beam pipeline in Dataflow as a job:

`apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error: Error processing pipeline.`

Checked Dataflow Job Log and seeing the time and error message:

2022-10-26 01:26:40.307 BST Error processing pipeline.

Comment: hi Emillia! Do you have screenshots? CAn you post any other logs that you get in the Dataflow UI?

Comment: @pablo cheers. I had found the source of the bug and fixed it. I appreciate your help!